# When Parse.com creates a sessionToken and what if this is expired?

Tags: session, parse-platform, parse-server

In parse dashboard in class `_Session`, all `sessionTokens` are being saved.
The following actions seem to trigger the creation:

- Login
- Sign up
- Upgrade

The first question is: Is there any other action that will create a new session Token?

And: I see that all token have an expiresAt field. Which is always set 1 year after token `createdAt`. Can i extent this period (e.g. to 2 years)?

Last: If this token is expired, and a user uses my app, what would happen then? The app will require a new log in (so a new token will be created)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct on the actions.

Parse-server allows for advance options on initialization.  Use `sessionLength` to set your expiry date.
If you using environmental variables it will be `PARSE_SERVER_SESSION_LENGTH`.

`sessionLength` - The length of time in seconds that a session should be valid for. Defaults to 31536000 seconds (1 year).

Depends what you doing client side. You can force log out if the session has expired.

Also note that when trying to run cloud code with an expired session the following error will show: `{"code":209,"message":"Session token is expired."}`

Comment: I have an extra question. what is sessionLength. Is it a class column or a built-in property? How can i set it from cloud? normally like: e.g. `token.set("sessionLength", "61536000");` ?

Comment: How are you running parse-server?

Comment: Using Express and the parse-server module

Comment: Normally set in your index.js file

Comment: Let me know if you get stuck. All deployments can be different if your setup is different. Self hosting, Heroku, AWS , they all differ. Must go in the constructor

Comment: @Cliffordwh - how would you do this in Azure? A la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840552/parse-server-config-options-in-azure

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this and wanted to build on the accepted answer.

1. Yes, the default sessionLength is 1 year but can be extended via a config param passed into the constructor of the ParseServer object.
2. When using Anonymous accounts this is a disaster situation. By design, the user can not re-authenticate after the session expires so they just lose all their data.
3. Reading the Parse Server source code I found another config setting `expireInactiveSessions` which defaults to true. I was able to pass in that config option as false and now `expiresAt` on the `Session` collection is `undefined`. Now anonymous user sessions never expire.
4. In my case, I use anonymous users but allow users to create a real account using email auth. Unfortunately, now those sessions never expire too. I didn't try it but I think you could set a trigger on the `Session` collection to provide an expiration for email based accounts and have anonymous sessions never expire. This would be the ideal solution.