# Parse Server Config Options In Azure

Tags: azure, parse-platform, parse-server, azure-web-app-service

I've installed a parse.com server in Azure.  All is working well with the initial setup.

I now want to lock down the server with a few of the "Advanced Options" as annotated on the Parse Server Github page.

I understand that I do these in the App Settings in Azure a la the below:

[image: Azure App Settings Photo]

Namely, sessionLength should be visible following a server restart?  However this is not the case as I still get 1 year sessions for newly logged in users.  Am I filling in the details incorrectly, is there an error with Azure & Parse Server, or am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it should be `SESSION_LENGTH`. You would need to check to see how its constructed in the `index.js`.

Update:

You could try Edit the config file and pass extra params like this:

```
  sessionLength : process.env.SESSION_LENGTH || 31536000 //Set to what you need
  enableAnonymousUsers : process.env.ENABLE_ANON_USERS || false,
  allowClientClassCreation: process.env.CLIENT_CLASS_CREATION || false,
```

github.com/mamaso/parse-server-azure-config

Look at the ENV variables listed : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/src/cli/definitions/parse-server.js

**OR**

Alternative you could update the session value on log-in or signup via a cloud code function.

Comment: Hi @Cliffordwh .  I can't fully work out where the index file is created from & how to best configure it.  I used the Parse Server Setup Wizard provided by Azure which pulls from this repository: https://github.com/Azure/parse-server-example.  It pulls the config file from here: https://github.com/mamaso/parse-server-azure-config.

Comment: The config file needs to be modified. I edited my answer!

Comment: thanks. So this would then rely on the input for say SESSION_LENGTH that you specify in the App Settings in Azure, or are you better specifying this directly in the index.js app?

Comment: Not sure how they structure it. You would just need to check